# Any example that adding schema.org/AggregateRating to the website is really SEO beneficial?

Tags: seo, schema.org

Do you know some real world examples that AggregateRating improved the website SEO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various consumers could do various things with this markup. You did not specify what counts as "improve" for you. How about displaying the review information in the result snippet for your page?

**Google Search** has the [Aggregate Ratings Rich Snippets](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/reviews#aggregate_ratings), which is currently shown like this (query: [`site:goodreads.com lord of the rings`](https://www.google.de/search?q=site:goodreads.com+lord+of+the+rings)):

> [image: Google Search: an example for the Aggregate Rating Rich Snippet]

**Bing** shows this in a similar way ([same search query](http://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Agoodreads.com+lord+of+the+rings)):

> [image: Bing: an example for the AggregateRating snippet]

The result (http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/33.The_Lord_of_the_Rings) is using Schema.org’s [`AggregateRating` type](http://schema.org/AggregateRating).

Comment: I assume this can help with CTR. Otherwise, I cannot see that it helps except to make the SERP link/snippet more attractive. I have not seen anything solid on whether reviews help or not. Is there any evidence of this you have seen?? Just curious if you have seen anything interesting. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc: Yeah, it seems likely that such snippets increase the CTR, which is why I suggested it as possible SEO benefit the OP might care about. --- As far as ranking is concerned, I prefer not to speculate (or try to conclude from third-party tests and observations) what might or might not go on in the ranking algorithms of search engines, so I fear I’m not the right contact for this topic.

Comment: While I am sure that review snippets will not give a SERP boost, I was curious about the CTR. It is good to hear your experience! Thanks for that!! I do not do reviews on my site, it just does not apply, so I had no real idea. I would like to see negative reviews. So far we can say something is good, but not if something is bad.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with improved the website SEO? It could mean some different things:

- if we mean SEO as a holistic approach to improve our user metrics and conversion, then yes, aggregateRating equals better CTR
- If you mean with improved SEO just any ranking factor, then yes too - if not already, then in short time the presence of [structured data will become a ranking factor](http://searchengineland.com/google-may-add-structured-markup-data-to-ranking-algorithm-230402).